# Difference between polling using ajax request and websockets

Tags: ajax, python-3.x, flask, websocket, socket.io

I am trying to continuously stream output on my flask app from my server to client (webapp). I am able to successfully stream output using by opening an ajax request and leaving it open like this:

```
//Open up a stream
let url = '/stream';
xhr.open('GET', url);
xhr.send(fd);

//Display it like this
data = xhr.responseText;
$(".myTextArea").val(data);
```

I can close this ajax request by doing this (but i'm leaving it open):

```
xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE
//do stuff
```

But I can also use websockets (`flask_socketio`) to continuously poll server output stream to the client.

Are these two methods of polling the same in terms of performance?

Here is how i am collecting the AJAX stream from remote server:

```
let streamTimer;
function stream(){
    let xhr;
    let streamData;
    let lastStreamData;
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    const url = '/stream';
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.send();
    let streamTimer = setInterval(function() {
        streamData = xhr.responseText;
        if (lastStreamData !== streamData) {
            console.log(streamData)
            lastStreamData = streamData;
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

My ajax calls my flask route `stream()` which basically tails a log with the `-f` option, that way it will keep the connection open. If there is output to the log then it will send it back to my ajax call and display it on the webpage.

```
def stream():
    def generate():
        if request.method == "POST":
            hostname = request.data.decode('utf-8')

            # ssh set up
            client = set_up_client()

            # Connect to hostname
            client.connect(hostname, username=USERNAME,
                           password=PASSWORD)

            cmd = ('tail -f -n0 /home/server.log')

            stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(cmd)

            for line in iter(lambda: stdout.readline(2048), ""):
                print(line, end="")
                yield line
                if re.search(r'keyword1|keyword2', line):
                    print('change detected')
                    yield 'change detected\n'

    return Response(stream_with_context(generate()), mimetype='text/html')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are these two methods of polling the same in terms of performance?

No they are not the same. You may not be sending a request to the server every X milliseconds, but you *are* polling the `XMLHttpRequest#responseText` getter every X milliseconds, which is overhead no matter how you look at it.

The good news is that you don't need an interval at all because the `XMLHttpRequest#onprogress` event handler is called every time data is sent from the server. Just move the content of your interval into an `onprogress` event handler for the request and you're good to go.

```js
let data;
const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', '/stream');
request.onprogress = function() {
    if(data === request.response) return;
    data = request.response;
    console.log(data);
};
request.send();
```

There is no polling in this example. The client simply handles `progress` events by updating the target element accordingly. If no updates are received for a while, we aren't running an interval every second just to check, so no harm done.

Is *this* the same performance as a socket? I don't have an answer for that, but I'm willing to bet that it is pretty darn close. Close enough that I would say "reasonably similar".

Now the one glaring difference I see between this method and a socket is that sockets enable two-way communication, whereas I have not been able to replicate sending data to the server more than once using the same request. It may be possible, but I haven't figured it out yet.

---

**Further abstraction**

You could abstract this by implementing a class that extends `XMLHttpRequest` like so:

```js
class ChunkedResponseRequest extends XMLHttpRequest {
    constructor(...args) {
        super(...args);
        this.data = null;
        this.addEventListener('progress', _ => {
            if(this.data === this.response) return;
            const chunk = this.data === null ? this.response 
                                             : this.response.substr(this.data.length);
            this.data = this.response;
            this.dispatchEvent(new MessageEvent('message', { data: chunk }));
        });
    }
}
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
const request = new ChunkedResponseRequest();
request.addEventListener('message', function({ data }) {
    console.log(data);
});
request.open('GET', '/stream');
request.send();
```

The value of the message event's `data` property will be the last response from the server.

---

**Implementation of a chunked response**

For those who would like to reproduce this behavior using Node.js (I personally don't work with Python or Flask), here's a quick example of a server that responds with an infinite number of chunks spaced one second apart:

```js
const http = require('http')
const requestHandler = (request, response) => {
    response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=UTF-8');
    response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'); // so we can access locally
    response.setHeader('Transfer-Encoding', 'chunked');
    (function send(i, delay) {
        setTimeout(_ => {
            response.write(i + '\r\n');
            send(i + 1, 1000);
        }, delay)
    })(0, 0);
}
const server = http.createServer(requestHandler)
server.listen(3000, (error) => error && console.log(error));
```

Make sure to set the URL of the `XMLHttpRequest` in the client side code to `http://localhost:3000` where `3000` is the port that the server is listening on. Obviously if you already have something listening on port `3000`, you'll want to select an unused port.

Comment: You are awesome!

Comment: I do my best :)

Answer (score 0):

No for the ajax polling you have to continuously hit the server to get the data, but in case of web socket you it's two way communications server can also connect with you.
If something have it will directly send you the data.

Comment: Ajax polling works for me though, i open an ajax connection and the server continuously sends back data. My connected is just doing a `tail -f mylog.log`. And the python generator sends it back to the webpage. I was wondering if there are disadvantages of doing it this way?

Comment: ajax will have one request and one response

Comment: Not exactly, check my updated post. My AJAX can have one request but keeps on getting multiple responses if the previous response is different. My question is, how is this different than sockets?

Comment: This answer would be correct if we were to be talking about traditional AJAX polling, but what we're talking about is a single request from the client to a server that responds with a chunked response. The "polling" is the client checking the response value for new data once every second.